# How to store java.sql.Date in cassandra date field using mapping manager?

Tags: java, sql, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Can someone help me to store the current system date in cassandra date column in format `yyyy-mm-dd` using Java? I get exception while saving the `java.sql.Date` using `MappingManager`.

***My sample program is:***

**Test.java**

```
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Table;
import java.sql.Date;
@Table(keyspace = "testing", name = "test")
public class Test {

    private String uid;
    private Date rece;

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public Date getRece() {
        return rece;
    }

    public void setRece(Date rece) {
        this.rece = rece;
    }


}
```

**TestDao.java**

```
Mapper mapper = new MappingManager(session).mapper(Test.class);
mapper.save(test);
```

***Cassandra Schema :***

```
CREATE TABLE tokenizer.test (
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    testdate date
) ;
```

Comment: A  `Date` [has no format](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date). And you could also **[edit]** the question and add the exception you're getting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43064780/2320144

Answer (score 1):

**Either declare data type of `rece` to `com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate` or Write a custom codec to encode `java.sql.Date` and register it to the cluster.**

Custom codec Example :

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate;
import com.datastax.driver.core.ProtocolVersion;
import com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec;
import com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.sql.Date;


public class DateCodec extends TypeCodec<Date> {

    private final TypeCodec<LocalDate> innerCodec;

    public DateCodec(TypeCodec<LocalDate> codec, Class<Date> javaClass) {
        super(codec.getCqlType(), javaClass);
        innerCodec = codec;
    }

    @Override
    public ByteBuffer serialize(Date value, ProtocolVersion protocolVersion) throws InvalidTypeException {
        return innerCodec.serialize(LocalDate.fromMillisSinceEpoch(value.getTime()), protocolVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(ByteBuffer bytes, ProtocolVersion protocolVersion) throws InvalidTypeException {
        return new Date(innerCodec.deserialize(bytes, protocolVersion).getMillisSinceEpoch());
    }

    @Override
    public Date parse(String value) throws InvalidTypeException {
        return new Date(innerCodec.parse(value).getMillisSinceEpoch());
    }

    @Override
    public String format(Date value) throws InvalidTypeException {
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

How to use it ?

Example :

```
CodecRegistry codecRegistry = new CodecRegistry();
codecRegistry.register(new DateCodec(TypeCodec.date(), Date.class));

try (Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().withCodecRegistry(codecRegistry).addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").withCredentials("cassandra", "cassandra").build(); Session session = cluster.connect("test")) {
    Mapper mapper = new MappingManager(session).mapper(Test.class);
    mapper.save(test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and As per Ashraful's answer, I have added below code in my model which resolved the issue.

```
Meta Data Model:

public class MetaData {
private String receive_date;
private String receive_hour;
**private com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate error_date;**
}

In my service class, added below code.
final MetaData metaData = MetaData.builder()
                    .receive_date(row.getString("receive_date"))
                    .receive_hour(row.getString("receive_hour"))
                    .error_date(row.getDate("error_date"))
                    .build();
```