# How to get cql date in java?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am using java8 and cassandra in my application. The datatype of current_date in cassandra table is 'date'. I am using entities in java to map to the table values. and the datatype in entity for the same field is java.sql.Date.

When I am trying to retrieve a record  'Select * from table where current_date='2017-06-06';' I am getting the following error'

```
`Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: ['org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.SimpleDateType' <-> java.sql.Date]
```

I have tried with various data types like :

> com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate, java.util.Date
>   ,com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken

all are returning the same errors.

I have referred http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/custom_codecs/extras/.

But I am stuck. Please help me out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45815737/2320144

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43064780/2320144

Comment: @AshrafulIslam declare data type  to com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate wont work. Getting same issue. Is there a direct data type in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Java driver will map `date` type into `com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate` Java type.

If you need to convert `date` to `java.time.LocalDate`, then you need to add extras to your project and either register codec globally as described in documentation:

```
cluster.getConfiguration().getCodecRegistry()
     .register(LocalDateCodec.instance);
```

Or you can specify codec for given column only:

```
@Column(codec = LocalDateCodec.class)
java.time.LocalDate date;
```

Similarly, the conversion could be made into Joda time types.

Comment: I can give @Column(codec = LocalDateCodec.class) .Then what should be the datatype for the field current_date  in java. Should it be com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate?

Comment: `com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate` doesn't require any extra codec - it should work by default.  The `LocalDateCodec` is used for conversion of `date` into `java.time.LocalDate` (I'll update answer)

Comment: I tried with java.time.LocalDate and getting the exception now :com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Value current_date is of type custom, not date

Comment: Works fine for me: https://gist.github.com/alexott/f9b91d81a21c97199e65c79451c26cd7 - please check your table definition