# Date in CASSANDRA

Tags: c#, datetime, cassandra, nosql

Is it possible to use and store **DATETIME** datatype in **CASSANDRA**
 database.

In NoSqlViewer i wrote:

```
CREATE TABLE DIRECTOR("ID" int,name text,surname text,date_birth date,PRIMARY("ID"));
```

I have WindowsForms project and I need dateTimePicker for date_birth column in table DIRECTOR. First of all, is it possible to use that or I do I have to make some specific format or something? How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving a DateTime to Cassandra Date column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260061/saving-a-datetime-to-cassandra-date-column)

Comment: I think so.but i still didn't get it right

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
please use this link for your reference https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/refDateTimeFormats.html

Comment: Please don't just link to documentation, expand on what the article says. The link isn't always guaranteed to work.